# Update JS and CSS in user browser automatically

Tags: javascript, angular, reload

We are making changes in our Angular application and pushing into production every day.

The problem: users have to reload the page to load the updated files.
This is not about caching, simply F5.

What is the best way to automatize page reloading if any change in frontend available?

We have come up with the following idea:
store the "version" in the database. Also store the "version" in Local Storage. Compare these values each request to the backend. If they differ - reload the page.

Comment: if your users just don't ever refresh the page you could schedule page reload with `setTimeout`, if that is not the case, you could setup a global error handler, that would open a modal saying that something is wrong, because, probably the app is not up to date, please refresh the page. If the problem persists...

Comment: Look into Service Workers and the [Web Periodic Background Sync API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Periodic_Background_Synchronization_API). You could use the API to poll if your current version differs with the version in the DB.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thank you, but it's experimental and doesn't work in Safari.

Comment: @Andrei setTimeout is not a good idea, because I need to reload the page if there is any update. Regarding error handler- most times there is no error, just updated JS and CSS files.

Comment: @Leeloo though the WPBS API is not well supported, the Service Worker API is and still offers you the posibility of polling for updates, without disturbing the UI thread. Either setup a Web Socket connection, or poll any now and then, in the Service Worker. If there is an update, send a message to the main thread to reload the page.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier would you be so kind to write in Answer block, so I could accept it?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using npm/webpack, you have to update the "version" in your package.json. Else, you can just put a version like 1.N.N at the end of your css or js files before the .extension. Changing names will force the browser to update assets files content. Next, you just have to manually (programmatically with ci/cd) update theses versions in the file names before you deploy in production.

Comment: This is not about caching. The users never reload the page in the browser.

Comment: You want it to be refreshed even if your user doesn't refresh the page ? Maybe with something like web sockets. <br/> 
But honestly, nobody doesn't close its browser and then reopen it  one per day. <br/>
If there is a service worker, I personnaly do a meta.json (updated in ci/cd) that I place in a public directory, and my service worker program check it to know if it should refresh the content.